# How can I control the type of the collection created by a collection expression?

Tags: c#, collections, language-design, c#-12.0

In C# 12, the following statement:

```
IList<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
```

can be replaced with the following:

```
IList<Node> nodes = [];
```

The documentation is here: [learn.microsoft.com - C# Language Reference - Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions)

I do not particularly care about this feature, but once we enable C# 12 in the shop, people will inevitably discover it and will start using it.

According to the documentation, (and indeed, as it can also easily be shown by experiment,) object expressions can be used to create instances not only for types which abide by a certain contract, but also for the following types:

- System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
- System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection
- System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList
- System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
- System.Collections.Generic.IList

So, in C# it is in fact possible to do the following:

```
IEnumerable<int> c1 = [1, 2];
IReadOnlyCollection<int> c2 = [2, 3];
IReadOnlyList<int> c3 = [3, 4];
ICollection<int> c4 = [4, 5];
IList<int> c5 = [5, 6];
```

In these cases, a very reasonable question to ask is: what types are instantiated here? The documentation doesn't say, so let's take a look with the debugger:

[image]

As it turns out, for mutable interfaces, collection expressions create instances of the `List<T>`. For immutable interfaces, they create instances of some `<>z__ReadOnlyArray<T>` type, which, as a bit of experimentation reveals, is just as defective as `List<T>`.

Why are they defective? Because their `Equals()` method does not actually check whether their contents are equal; instead, it defers to `object.Equals()`, which simply does a reference comparison. So, you may have two instances of `List<T>` with the exact same contents, and they will report themselves as unequal.

So far I have been able to use the ["Banned API Analyzers"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md) to prevent people from using `List<T>` in the shop, but I do not know how to specify a rule for `<>z__ReadOnlyArray<T>`, and even if I could, collection expressions hide the type that is being instantiated, so the analyzers will not flag those instantiations. (They do not flag `IList<int> c5 = [5, 6];` which instantiates a `List<int>`.)

How can I control which types are instantiated by collection expressions when these expressions are used for the creation of collection interfaces?

The documentation explains how to create a new collection type which abides by the necessary contract, but it does not show any means of telling the compiler to use that type when creating instances to back the collection interfaces.

Comment: You could just set `dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression = false:error` in .editorconfig. Then they can't use it. Problem solved.

Comment: AFAIK you can't (at least at the moment) since the inferred collection type is determined by the compiler and the [feature specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/collection-expressions) does not mention any ability to customize type used as far as I can see

Comment: What annoys *me* about the analyzer (more than the feature itself) is that it wants to want to convert `some_long_multi_line_expression.ToList()` into `[.. some_long_multi_line_expression]`, which obscures the conversion to a list and looks a lot worse in the real world than it does here in this comment. There are three different analyzer rules governed by that .editorconfig rule (IDE0300, IDE0301, IDE0305) so they have to be configured individually by ID if you're okay with collection expressions in general but don't want the spread operator instead of `.ToList()`.

Comment: @madreflection I just now got the chance to test this. From the looks of it, using `dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression = false:error` prevents offering to ~ruin~ convert existing code to collection expressions, but it will not flag their use. So, it will not prevent, or even slightly inconvenience, anyone from using them if they want to.  So, the "then, they can't use it" part of your comment seems wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, that rule appears to be buggy. If you set `csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types` to `false:error`, you get an error for using `var i = 0;`, and if you set it to `true:error`, you get an error fot `int i = 0;`. That rule is symmetric. I assumed that `dotnet_style_prefer_collection_expression` would be symmetric as well, but `warning` and `error` only work for `true`.  So, yes, my comment was incorrect, but it shouldn't have been. I suggest filing a bug on this since it should do exactly what you want when set to `false:error`.

Comment: @madreflection you are right.